# Multi-level Collapsable Menu - Cannot Reach Item Positioned After Submenu

Tags: css

I am unable to reach the list element that is positioned at level 2, right after the level 3 submenu because when I hover out of the level 3 submenu the whole menu collapses to level 1.

The item that I am unable to reach is titled "Unreachable" in the code.

N.B.: I am able to reach the item if I bypass the level 2 menu, i.e. approach it without triggering level 2. But most of the time, the end user will hover over level 2 before approaching that item and will not be able to reac it.

```css
.side-nav-bar-menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 19.692em;
  padding-top: 0.385em;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
 
.side-nav-bar-menu li:hover {
  background-color: blue
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul li {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul li ul li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-nav-bar-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>L1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>L2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a>L2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>L3</a></li>
            <li><a>L3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Unreachable</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>L1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>L2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because you set the width of your containing div to 19.692em and hide the overflow. As an aside you should use classes as your css selectors are very inefficient

Comment: I tried removing the width and overflow. But that had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with new fix**

Try this:

```css
.side-nav-bar-menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 19.692em;
  padding-top: 0.385em;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
 
.side-nav-bar-menu li:hover {
  background-color: blue
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul li {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.side-nav-bar-menu ul li ul li ul li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-nav-bar-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>L1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>L2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a>L2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>L3</a></li>
            <li><a>L3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Reachable</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>L1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>L2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is quite subtle to the uninitiated like me.

Comment: But now all level 1 items are expanded when I hover over any one of them. Is there another way?